# How to config the file path in webpack?

Tags: css, webpack

I'm new to webpack. I want to ask how can I custom a file path in webpack.

Here is the code I've tested:

```
(function () {
    var webpack = require('webpack'),
        path = require('path'),
        BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin'),
        ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            'site': ['./assets/js/site']
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/assets/',
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/assets/js'),
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/i,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'stage-1'],
                            compact: false
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    test: /(\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$)|(\.woff2?(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$)/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '../fonts/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|bmp|gif|ico)/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '../images/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader'])
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new BabiliPlugin({}, { test: /\.min\.js$/ }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery'
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/bundle.css')
        ]
    };
}());
```

I want to ask about these lines:

```
use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '../fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }
}]
```

When I set the `name` starts with `../`, it compiles exactly right except the `url` which is inside the file `bundle.css`, like this snapshot:

[image]

Then, I've tried to remove the characters `../` from the name, the `fonts` folder was created inside `js` folder (it's not my goal). But the `url` inside the file `bundle.css` folder is right (I want this path - `/assets/fonts/...`).

[image]

How can I edit it?

p/s: May you embed the two images to my question? it doesn't appear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set a context in your loader's options. By default the current working directory is used.

I'm not sure what your src directory structure is, so I'm taking a guess.

```
use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: 'assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
        context: './src/assets/fonts/'
    }
}]
```